# ROS kinetic arch linux installation

Tags: ros, archlinux

I am trying to install ROS kinetic from this AUR package:https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ros-kinetic-desktop-full/

However,I am getting thie following errors:

Using Yay:

```
> Error: Could not find all required packages:
    pkg-config>=0.28 (Wanted by: ros-kinetic-desktop-full -> ros-kinetic-simulators -> ros-kinetic-gazebo-ros-pkgs -> ros-kinetic-gazebo-plugins -> ros-kinetic-gazebo-dev -> gazebo -> ignition-fuel_tools -> ignition-msgs)
```

Using Pikaur:

```
Version mismatch:
ignition-msgs depends on: 'pkg-config'
 found in 'PackageSource.REPO': '{'pkg-config': '1.5.2-1'}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is why versioned dependencies in Arch Linux are **ugly**. The pkg-config package no longer exists, since Arch has transitioned to using the [pkgconf](http://pkgconf.org/) implementation. However, even though pkgconf declares a virtual "provides" for pkg-config, in order to ease the transition, this provides is not versioned and therefore breaks the dependency resolution for the "ignition-msgs" package.

As a separate matter, it is completely wrong for **any** package to have a make dependency on either pkgconf or pkg-config, since whichever one Arch Linux uses has always been in the "base-devel" group which is **required** for running `makepkg` and is assumed always available.

t;dr "ignition-msgs" is broken because the AUR maintainer is bad at packaging, see the comments on the package details.

Comment: @eschwartz- Any hope of getting this fixed in the near future?

Comment: There are comments on the package details, if it doesn't get fixed in a reasonable span of time you can submit an orphan request so you can fix it yourself.